# IntelliJ Error : "Cannot Resolve Symbol" in all maven dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, aspectj

I can run the application with "maven jetty:run", but I'm seeing errors in IDEA

My pom.xml => http://pastebin.com/r3fMqShp

Step 1:

[image: Error]

---

Step2:

[image: Error2]

None of the following worked so far:

- Change/Upgrade JDK(jdk1.7.0_51)
- mvn clean install
- Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Reimport All Maven Projects

Thanks

Comment: There is an option somewhere in Maven project submenu that "refreshes" the pom dependencies (and I don't mean the Reimport... one). Can't remember the exact name but it has "indicies something" in it's name. It helped me several times when I had that problem, it loads/refreshes everything and magically makes things work.

Comment: Not that it's related to your problem, but make sure to remove the duplicate `spring-web` & `spring-context` dependencies you have just before the build section

Comment: I removed but still not working @Grove

Comment: If you go to `File -> Project Structure -> Libraries` can you find in the list `spring-web` & `spring-context`?

Comment: I searched "indicies" word in IDEA Settings but nothing found @mareckmareck

Comment: yes there is both @Grove 

Maven: org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.3.RELEASE and 

Maven: org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: Try enabling auto-import `File -> Settings -> Project settings section -> Maven -> Importing -> Import maven projects automatically`. If this does not work I'd try recreating the project from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved ! :)

The problem stems from the fact that the operating system language is Turkish. After Changing to English, problem solved